# Google App Engine - First Request is slow

Tags: php, google-app-engine, amp-html

I have a question regarding Google App Engine. I know that the first request will take longer time than second because of how instances are scaled. But in my case the difference is very huge. I have no manual scaling, just a standard automatic scaling and i would want to have some recommendation of what i should do.

**This is my case:**
I have an AMP project(https://amp.dev/) of an e-commerce website. So i do not have any static URL that i can setup a warmup-request that Google App Engine recommend. The url is like this: `amp.store/product/{productname}`, so the `{productname}` is dynamic, i have over 1000 products and cannot send request to those url just to keep my instance live at all time.

**app.yaml:**

```
runtime: php55
api_version: 1
service: amp-page

handlers:
- url: .*
  script: main.php

skip_files:....
```

When i try the `PageSpeed Insights` from Google i get this error on first try:

> Lighthouse returned error: ERRORED_DOCUMENT_REQUEST. Lighthouse could
>   not reliably load the requested page. Check that you are testing the
>   correct URL and that the server is responding properly to all
>   requests. (Status code: 500)

Now when i try again just right after i often get **84/100(mobile)** **99/100(desktop)**.

This is a huge difference, this is why i am asking. Would it solve the problem with Manual Scaling or is there any other way to keep my instance or request faster like the second try?

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to create a cron job via your cron.yaml file that would request a known page every X minutes to ensure you always have one instance running.

Create a single handler in your application that executes a php script and returns some sort of output. Something that isn't database heavy. Could be as simple as an echo "ok";

Comment: the problem i am having would not help with sending request to the server. Because if i CRON on productA then productB would take long time as shown above. ProductA will respond fast because it was hit by a request. You can see that on those 2 links above for test URL. If you visit productA and then productB it would take same amount of time

Comment: Are you sure that the problem is App Engine Scaling? The problem you describe sounds more like a symptom of your database's query cache. Check the instances page and see if you have an instance running. If you do and the request is still slow, then scaling is not the problem.

Comment: You can use the console dashboard to see number of instances running over time.  The log output will also indicate "This request caused a new process to be started for your application" for cold starts.

Comment: Thanks @JeffDeskins the problem was not scaling but the API itself and uses caching for DB queries (memcache) that's why. Just noticed my app is slow because of the API :(. Thanks for the clarifications.

Comment: @AliDurrani so it was my comment under this answer? Glad to help! Good luck

Answer (score 2):

To keep at least one instance running (even if there is no traffic) you want to set the **min_instances** `app.yaml` [scaling element](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/config/appref#scaling_elements) to `1`:

> **min_instances**
>
> Optional. The minimum number of instances for App Engine to create for
>   this module version. These instances serve traffic when requests
>   arrive, and continue to serve traffic even when additional instances
>   are started up as required to handle traffic.
>
> Specify a value from 0 to 1000. You can set the parameter to the value
>   0 to allow scaling to 0 instances to lower costs when no requests are
>   being served. Note that you are charged for the number of instances
>   specified whether they are receiving traffic or not.
>
> **Important**: If you use appcfg from the App Engine SDK for PHP to deploy, you cannot use this parameter in your **app.yaml**. Instead,
>   set the parameter as described in [Setting Autoscaling Parameters in
>   the API Explorer](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/config/setting-autoscaling-params-in-explorer), or by using the [App Engine Admin API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/reference/rest/v1/apps.services.versions/patch).

Otherwise the automatic scaling will shutdown your idling instance(s), making the next request a (long) loading request.

Side note: you can also [configure warmup requests](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/configuring-warmup-requests) (creating their URL is part of that, it's not an arbitrary static URL) to reduce even further the chances of user requests becoming loading requests. You cannot eliminate them completely - instances do not live forever and warmup requests aren't 100% effective, they're just a best-effort solution.

Comment: This is a good note too. The question didn't explicitly say `automatic_scaling ` and it is only implied for `F1` instances so I assumed `basic_scaling` which only has a max option.

Comment: I assumed automatic scaling (the default) as no scaling config was showing in the app.yaml file.

Comment: Also, look at other parameters such as `min_pending_latency`, which is deliberately set to 500 ms for free apps, says the official app.yaml reference document.